# Run a aspx page into a Sharepoint folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, sharepoint

I have a aspx page and I'd like to run it into a sharepoint folder. Is there a way to execute this page like a html page? What I really need is to run a c# code that is together the aspx page (code behind) to read a SQLite database and shows the result in a good interface (html-css-javascript).

Obs.: I have a assembly reference for the SQLite.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an application page inside sharepoint and move your code in that application page. its very simple, please see this link.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/how-to-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-application-page-using-visual-studio-2010/

Please note that application page only support web forms and not MVC

Answer (score 0):

Not sure "run it into a sharepoint folder" means... You can't have page with code behind in regular SharePoint folders.

You can put ASPX pages (even with codebehind) in Layouts folder on server's disk and they will be avaiable with ....\layouts\your_page.aspx urls.

Comment: i dont know nothing about sharepoint, but there are like shared folders where I can put things, like a explorer folder. They call it sharepoint there... so it act like folders, so i'd like to kwon how to run this aspx page into a folder, like we open a html file. thanks by attention

Comment: @JoãoPauloOliveiraFernandes I think you would benefit from looking into the SharePoint way of [creating application pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231581.aspx). Some things that SharePoint exposes as a "folder" aren't really an actual filesystem folder at all, and the security environment differs depending on these factors. As Alexei suggests here, the general way to get a codebehind-containing aspx page to run in SharePoint is to use files under the layouts folder, also known as application pages.